# Making file names in a directory link to their respective pages - php

Tags: php, html, directory, hyperlink

I have some php that takes file names out of a /portfolio/ directory and turns it into an unordered list

```
<?php $dir = 'portfolio'; // The directory containing the files. 
$ext = '.html'; // The file extension. 
?> 

<ul> <?php foreach (glob($dir . '/*' . $ext) as $file) { ?> 
<li><?php echo basename($file, $ext); ?></li> 
<?php } ?> </ul>
```

How would you get them to be links that linked to their respective pages? Many thanks x

Comment: You're going to get your folder showing up twice as your URL if you use your present code, along with `wheybags'` answer below. I replied to your original question under Terry's answer, but you never replied. I'll call it a `learning curve`.

Comment: @Fred Brilliant thanks, seems to be working nicely. I didn't see the oter one of your replies sorry, new to this and all. x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead, it won't double up on the folder URL:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file, $ext); ?></a></li>
```

(tested)

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $dir . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file, $ext); ?></a></li>
```

?

Comment: Thanks, I took out the '$dir . $file' and kept it as '$file' as it was linking me to ../portfolio/portfolio/file.html! Great fix though thanks. Is there any way to make the files name that the browser is on at the moment invisible or not show up? thanks x